# ¿Qué son los "farolillos" en "no tengo el chichi para farolillos"?

Tags: expresiones, coloquialismos, españa, vulgaridades, modismos

He oído la expresión ***no tengo el chichi para farolillos***, a modo de imitación del desparpajo y del acento de los españoles. Si no me equivoco, en España significa "ahora no estoy de humor".

Por lo que veo, el *chichi* es el pene. Pero los *farolillos* no adivino qué son. El diccionario solo dice que son "faroles" y también ciertas especies de plantas con flores acampanadas. No agrega ninguna definición coloquial.

¿A qué se refieren con *farolillos*?

Comment: "Chichi" son los genitales femeninos no los masculinos. Por otra parte nunca he oído esa expresión, sin embargo hay otra similar con ese significado también: "No tengo el coño para ruidos".

Comment: No busqué "chichi" en ninguna parte, sólo fue una suposición por el contexto. Me causa gracia. No lo voy a editar dado que en las respuestas está la corrección.

Comment: 'No tener el coño para farolillos' puede también emplearse cuando ha pasado algo que te tiene muy descontento y por esa razón tienes un bajo umbral para tolerar otros eventos que normalmente no serían un problema grave. Por ejemplo: 1. Se te cae el móvil al suelo. 2. Eso te pone de mal humor. 3. Un compañero hace una broma inocente, unos minutos después. 4. Esa broma te sienta mal, porque estás de mal humor. O sea... 'No tienes el coño para farolillos', o menos vulgar (pero todavía vulgar): 'No está el horno para bollos'.

Comment: Acepto la definición dada por @blonfu et al para esta frase, dado que se popularizó por un programa de televisión de España, pero "chichi" en otros contextos y otros países tiene otras acepciones: http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Chichi.php

Comment: Serie "Allí abajo", T4E9, 09:28: "Mira, Carmen, que no tengo el chocho pa'farolillos".

Comment: Interesante. En México, *chichi* (tal como *las chichis*) denomina busto. Pero, *chocha* denomina vagina. En mismo tema, en Japonés, pene es vulgarmente *chinchin*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La palabra *chichi*, como bien apunta @blonfu en los comentarios, suele referirse a los genitales femeninos:

> **[chichi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8iwXb8F)**
>
> 1. m. vulg. coño (‖ vulva y vagina).

Aunque para el caso que nos ocupa daría igual que fuesen los masculinos.

Los farolillos son esos objetos de papel, iluminados por dentro, que se ponen en las ferias y fiestas para adornar y dar ambiente festivo:

> **[farolillo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=He0Yalm)**
>
> 1. m. Farol de papel, celofán o plástico de colores, que sirve para adornar en verbenas y fiestas.

[image]

Y sí, efectivamente, la expresión quiere decir que no se está de humor para fiestas (o para lo que sea).

Answer (score 4):

Definitivamente el *chichi* se refiere a los genitales femeninos, de hecho la frase se suele usar principalmente por mujeres. Ten en cuenta que su significado de "ahora no estoy de humor" se puede interpretar muy fácilmente en el terreno del acto sexual ("ahora no tengo ganas" u "hoy no puedo").

En cuanto a los *farolillos*, observa la siguiente foto:

[image: Farolillos]

Esta foto corresponde a la Feria de abril de Sevilla. Los farolillos son las filas de bolas rojas y blancas que ves sobre la calle (recubriendo las bombillas que la iluminan), y son un símbolo de la Feria, ya que no solo adornan las calles sino también el interior de muchas casetas. Por tanto, en este caso *farolillos* hace alusión a la Feria, y por extensión a las ganas de fiesta con las que uno asiste a la Feria.

Por tanto, la frase quiere decir que "no se tienen ganas de fiesta".

Answer (score 3):

*Chichi* es una de las miles de formas que se usan en España para referirse a los genitales de la mujer.

En cuanto a la frase completa *no tengo el chichi para farolillos*, se usa  de forma coloquial en España desde que se mencionara en la serie española [*7 vidas*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/7_vidas) en algún momento de su emisión, entre 1999 y 2006, por parte del personaje Aída.

Por tanto, vendría a ser algo así como *no tengo el coño para fiestas*, tal y como apunta [walen en su buena respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22799/1674).

Mirando [Google Trends](https://trends.google.es/trends/explore?date=2004-01-01%202017-10-18&q=no%20tengo%20el%20chichi%20para%20farolillos) se observa que tuvo su auge hacia 2004 (o lo mismo antes, pero la aplicación no mira nada previo a ese año) y ha ido decayendo:

[image]

Yo nunca la he oído, pero esto tampoco quiere decir nada. Sin embargo, viendo la gráfica no me extrañaría que acabe cayendo en desuso con el tiempo si no es *rescatada* por alguna otra mención en televisión.

Yo asumo que la dijo el personaje de Aída, interpretado por Carmen Machi, de ahí que muchas referencias hablen de ella como autora de la frase. Fundéu, por ejemplo, [cita](http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/el-rincon-del-buen-decir-gracias-a-la-tele-5711/) esta frase como propia del *spin-off* Aída que se emitió años después (2005-2014, por lo que no tendría sentido dado que ya en 2004 se usaba la frase).

Por cierto, encontré el [vídeo donde aparece la frase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXOiHmPqP34), pero está bloqueado por el productor. Lo dejo aquí por si algún día se le levanta el veto y así podemos saber con exactitud el capítulo en el que se dijo.

Comment: Me acuerdo de la emisión de ese capitulo,hablo de memoria, pero la protagonista de la serie, Aida mencionaba esa frase en una discusión y por alguna razón se grabó y se hizo viral, le invitaban a programas de TV solo para que repitiera la frase, quería tratar lo efímiera que es la fama, pues al poco la gente se aburría y ya no lo hace gracia, En definitiva la frase "No Tengo el chichi para farolillos" debe de ser genuina de la serie de Aida, los picos del gráfico deben corresponder a la emisión y remisiones del capitulo y la continuidad final al lanzamiento de la serie en dvd

Comment: @Xenione yo nunca la he oído en directo, pero supongo que hacia 2004-2005 sí debía estar presente en alguna conversación informal. ¿La oíste tú?

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de llegar a este post y aunque es muy antiguo lo voy a contestar.

Chichi se refiere a los genitales femeninos, y farolillos viene de la antigüedad, cuando las prostitutas se anunciaban con farolillos en las puertas, para que las ubicaran por las noches.

Por consiguiente, la frase de no tengo el chichi para farolillos significa que hoy no tengo ganas de trabajar (prostituírme) y todas sus posibles derivaciones, entendiéndose como que hoy no tienes ganas de aguantar a nada ni nadie molesto.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido al sitio! La teoría que comentas es interesante, sin embargo la expresión solo parece usarse desde épocas muy recientes, el uso más antiguo que he podido encontrar es de 2004, por lo que no tiene sentido que se use "farolillos" con un significado que hoy en día ya no se usa. ¿Podrías indicar en qué te basas para afirmar esto?